# Get list characters error regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex validation :

```
return Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^[a-z]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I want to get all the characters which doesn't correspond to the regex

For example, if the user types a1z!2, I want to get {1,2,!}.
Can I do this in C# with the regex methods.
Thanks

Comment: How complex is your regex likely to be? The sample you have posted can be done without using regex at all

Comment: `Regex.Matches("[^a-z]")`

Comment: the real regex is more difficult ; here it's just an example

Comment: This example is trivial and essentially, a typo. It's not possible to help unless you ask about the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to negate the character class by adding a `^` to the class 
as

```
[^a-z]
```

- `[^a-z]` Matches anything other than `a-z`

**Example**

```
string pattern = "[^a-z]";
string input = "a1z!2";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
    Console.WriteLine( m.Value);
```

will give output as

```
1
!
2
```

- `Regex.Matches(input, pattern)` will return a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection`.
- `foreach` will iterate through the collections.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `^` and `$` anchors. As it is, you are asking for matches where *all* characters from beginning to end are non alphabetic.

The proper regex should be `"[^a-z]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
string toSearchString = "your string here";
Match match = new Regex("*some pattern here*").Match(toSearchString );
string unmatchedString = toSearchString.Replace(match.Value,"");
```

this will give you the unmatched string characters.

Comment: Even if this worked, why do that instead of asking directly for the unmatched characters? This has several issues though: it assumes only a single match and creates a temporary strings during replacement.

Comment: True.. I was trying to replace the same string as such... Yours will be the easiest...